# Parsing page data into sidebar - wordpress

Tags: wordpress

What would be the proper procedure for accessing the current page html data and picking up all  of a certain tag and throwing them into the sidebar as links?

Comment: The thought process for this doesn't make much sense.  If you already have an html structure in your page, can you not just shape it to what a slider plugin already uses (say bxslider) with a class?  Or you could use a custom post type, and loop through the posts to make your slider, embedding it with a shortcode.  Could you give a bit more information on how you are using it, any code you have?

Comment: My intent is to take the content on the page, and run through it picking up all of the h2 tags in the page. Then, in the sidebar, I would use those collected h2 tags to create a navigation of sorts that would just highlight the headings of what is on the page so that without scrolling down the whole page you already know what is all there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your proficiency with php, but I'll give you and overview of what you'd probably want to do.

First, you need the HTML.  I'm assuming you're running this on a page (in a page.php file or single.php file, or similar), this means that you have access to the global variable $post, which contains the html of the page in it.  To access it you can use the helper function `get_the_content()`, this returns the html being displayed.
Next you need to parse through this to get the h2 tags.  A simple regex can handle this, something like `<h2[^>]*>(.*)</h2>`.  It's important to remember that this regex is very picky, so format your html correctly, no multiline h2s.
So now you have the html, and have parsed it with a regex to get the h2s.  Now you need to generate the list from the results, and prepend it to the top of the content of the page.  There are a ton of ways to do this, the easiest being just running the code in the right spot in the template file.

Of course there are probably better ways of doing this, I'd recommend you look at say a FAQ plugin (if that's what this is for), or do the lists manually (as this system can be broken), or possibly use a custom post type; but for your question, that's how I'd do it.